# C# Get constants from nested classes with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, constants

I'd like to create a List from all of the constants in the nested classes.

```
public struct SomePair
{
    public string Name, Value;

    public SomePair(string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}

private static MemberInfo[] GetClasses() => typeof(MainFoo).GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public);
private static List<Type> GetClassTypes() => GetClasses().Select(c=>c.GetType()).ToList();

public static class MainFoo
{
    // The return value should contain the information about the SomeConstant's from both Errors and Foo.
    public static List<LocalizationPair> Dump()
    {
        List<SomePair> Dump = new List<SomePair>();
        var classes = GetClassTypes();
        foreach (Type cls in classes)
        {
            var constants = cls.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public); // <<< Is always empty...
            foreach (FieldInfo constant in constants)
            {
                Dump.Add(new SomePair(
                    $"{cls.Name}.{constant.Name}",
                    constant.GetValue(cls).ToString()
                    ));
            }
        }

        return Dump;
    }
    
    public static class Errors
    {
        public constant string SomeConstant = "a";
    }
    
    public static class Foo
    {
        public constant string SomeConstant = "a";
    }
}
```

I'm able to get a list of all classes and a list of all class-types but once I try to use GetMember() on those, it returns nothing.

Comment: I don't see a call to `GetNestedTypes` anywhere, so start there. Second, you need to include `BindingFlags.Instance` and/or `BindingFlags.Static` to get any results. Constants are static members. Third, `.Select(c => c.GetType())` is going to project the `Type` instance for a `RuntimeFieldInfo`, `RuntimePropertyInfo`, etc. from the sequence. You need to cast each item (`c`) to `FieldInfo`, `PropertyInfo`, etc. depending on which it is, and get the `FieldType` or `PropertyType` property, respectively. It's not going to be a simple lambda expression.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I didn't even know that method existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GetNestedTypes() instead with the correct BindingFlags for public constants:

```
var nestedTypes = typeof(MainFoo).GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public);
foreach (Type type in nestedTypes)
{
    FieldInfo[] constants = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
    // <do stuff here>
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.